# DOS behavior of Van Hove singularity in a line

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, asymptotics, density-of-states

When there are some points in momentum space give $|\nabla_k \varepsilon_k|=0$, they are called Van Hove points and give singularity in the desity of states (DOS). But what if  $|\nabla_k \varepsilon_k|=0$ is zero along a line or in a surface.

For example, consider a dispersion relation in 1D like
$$\varepsilon_k = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 & |k| \le 1 \\
|k|-1 & |k| > 1 \, .
\end{array}
\right.$$
What kind of divergence near $\epsilon=0$? It seems that the DOS for all $\varepsilon>0$ is a constant and suddenly goes to infinity when $\varepsilon$ is fine tuning to zero.

What about more general cases in 2D or 3D?

Comment: This is better. But the links at the end don't seem to add anything; I think you could safely take them out, and it would improve the question. I suggested linking to your other questions because you said they were closely related, so I thought you'd write them in such a way that it would provide useful context to links to the other parts, but actually each of these new questions is fairly self-contained; the links seem unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah...I rewrote those questions so that they are more self-contained as indenpendent posts. I'll take those links out.

Comment: Cool, that helps. Sorry, I didn't mean to imply you _had_ to link the questions amongst each other (in case that was the impression you got).